# CR/LF Encoding to PDF file

Tags: c#, encoding, newline

I just ran into a problem I haven't seen before. The problem short is that I need to send two different strings to a method which will validate if the string are the same.

one of the string look like this

Sample 1

```
JVBERi0xLjQNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFu
ZyhkYS1ESykgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDU3IDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4v
```

the second one looks like

Sample 2    `ZyhkYS1ESykgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDU3IDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4vZyhkYS1ESykgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDU3IDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4v`

The actually string is a PDF document compressed into base64 (this is only a part of it)

I tried to take sample one into notepad++ and say show all special characters, it shows me CRLF in the end of each line.

Now im in the situation that i need to have sample 2 looking like sample 1, so I need to read a file into the same encoding, is this possible?

So to sum up here is what I want to do

EDIT/ADD:

What i want is that 
1. Take a pdf 
2. Convert it into base64encoded with cr/lf 
3. in a validation method in another library it needs to be validated as this format.

Comment: Read all bytes is using wrong type encoding.  Try this :            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("FileName", Encoding.UTF8);
            string input = reader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: Your two samples do not represent the same data, even ignoring line breaks. Also, base64 is not a compression algorithm; it simply re-encodes data so that it can be transmitted using ASCII (in fact, it _expands_ the data in the process, though this is a side-effect rather than the actual goal). If you always have base64 data and want to ensure different instances represent the same data, then the right approach is to simply decode the data and compare the binary result. Unfortunately, it is not clear at all from your question _what_ it is exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: What i want is that

1. Take a pdf 
2. Convert it into base64encoded with cr/lf
3. in a validation method in another library it needs to be validated as this format.

added to the question as well thanks for the note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didnt find any nice way to create a CR/LF split

```
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Testdata\SSVALID.pdf");

        string temp_inBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

        string returnString = "";

        int maxLenght = 76;

        int counts = temp_inBase64.Length / maxLenght;

        for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
        {
            returnString += temp_inBase64.Substring((i * 76), 76);
            returnString += "\r\n";
        }

        returnString += temp_inBase64.Substring(76 * counts, temp_inBase64.Length - (76 * counts));
```